# Intel Wireless N 5300 - Personal Area Network Support

Tags: wireless, drivers

My wireless card supports what Intel calls "MyWifi" which means that it can act as an access point for other computers. How can I discover if this is supported in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be to do the following in a terminal:

- turn off network-manager
- try to enable master mode for your card

Here's the terminal commands:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
```

If this gives an error, you will probably need a patched driver to enable it. I get this error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I don't know how to make an accesspoint with a GUI, as I've never had a network card that supports it.

You can turn on network-manager again by running

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: Thanks. I do indeed get that error. What resources can I use to locate a patch?

Comment: I'm not sure that is an easy task. I've only tried to patch to enable monitoring and injection, and I've usually found these through the aircrack-ng community.